# Five cubic dice were rolled

Tags: mathematics

Five cubic dice were rolled, and the product of the numbers obtained was 432. What is the largest possible sum of five such numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we assume these are regular dice being rolled one at a time, the answer would be

> 6+6+6+2+1=**21**

...unless, of course,

> the method of rolling the dice was left intentionally vague: one could throw *three dice at once* followed by two single rolls and get 18+6+4=**28** instead.

Answer (score 0):

...unless, of course

> Using 'existing' dice: Backgammon uses a doubling dice with value 16 on one of its sides. Mix that with 4 normal dice to get 16+3+3+3+1 = 26

However:

> The maximum is unbounded. It seems obvious that it is not intended as a trick question, but you only need (for example) one face with value 1/n (rolled 4 times) and another with value n^4*432.

Comment: Our answers can be combined for a score of gjb uhaqerq rvtugrra...

Comment: Not sure how you got that total, but: Gur onpxtnzzba qbhoyvat qvpr vf n phor nf erdhrfgrq gung bayl tbrf gb guvegl-gjb. Rvtugl-bar vf gur pbzovarq znk

Comment: oeps that should be 64 and 148

Comment: Ah, a sixth cube must have slipped in while I was calculating

Answer (score 0):

The regular cubic backgammon dice have a number of dots from 1 to 6. The divisors of 432 are 1,2,3,4,6 the best chance to obtain the maximum sum is if the the combination has the most divisors. If we assume we throw  one or two dice at a time we obtain the following combinations and their sum.

6,6,6,2,1        the sum is   21

4,4,3,3,3        the sum is 17

6,6,4,3,1        the sum is 20

6,4,3,3,2        the sum is  18

To obtain the maximum sum 6+6+6+6+6=30 we have the least probability. In addition to that $6^5$ is far greater than 432.
So I will bet as maximum sum 20.